# UITransitionView stuck on the top of views hierarchy

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch

When presenting a quick preview screen from a `UITextView` using 3D Touch, I'm getting a warning **`[UIPreviewItemController stopInteraction]`** called more than once after start Interaction. This is unexpected, please file a radar."

When I press harder the app redirects me to Safari and opens a web page.
Then when I open the application it seems like **`UITransitionView`** stuck on the screen and I couldn't proceed to work with app.

It seems like it's iOS bug because I don't use any custom views or transitions.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue?

[Sample project](https://github.com/ySirko/QuickPreviewSample) 
It's just Single View app with `UITextView`.

**Example:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/hm38bz9bo8ryt0a/IMG_1755.TRIM.MOV?dl=0

**Views hierarchy**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIq9l.png

**Edited:** I can reproduce this bug 10% of the time.

Comment: Your example link doesn't work. Please edit your question.

Comment: Do you happen to have a demo project for that? Or post some codes.

Comment: @mkUltra are you sure that link doesn't work?

Comment: @Glenn Added link to demo project.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. I'm using iOS 11.x. Probably an iOS 12+ bug indeed? Could you try removing that transitionView manually by enumerating the subviews or child views of your controller?

Comment: @Yura Sirko, It might be my problem, sorry man.

Comment: @Glenn probably it's the only way to fix this problem.

Comment: Yea, so far that's the only way I can think of. Or you can further search for the same issue here on SO. Good luck.

Comment: did u ever figure this out? i have something similar, but `uitransitionview` takes place of the app `rootViewController`, completely removing my `UITabBarController` after being redirected back from safari using `firebase facebook oauth`